# Joomla system plugin running more than once

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I've created a Joomla system plugin that records on a database table all url parameters to do some analytics using logged in users.

The plugin works fine, the problem is it seems to be running more than once on a single page load. When a user opens a page I get 2 new records, and they have 1 or 2 seconds difference on the datahora column.

The plugin is running on onAfterRender, please see code bellow.

What could cause the plugin to run more than once? I've also tried running it onAfterInitialise, but I got the same results. 
Thanks

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

jimport( 'joomla.factory' );

class plgSystemLogAccessUser extends JPlugin
{
    /**
     * Load the language file on instantiation. Note this is only available in Joomla 3.1 and higher.
     * If you want to support 3.0 series you must override the constructor
     *
     * @var    boolean
     * @since  3.1
     */
    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

    /**
     * Plugin method with the same name as the event will be called automatically.
     */

    function onAfterRender()
    {       
        /*
        * Plugin code goes here.
        * You can access database and application objects and parameters via $this->db,
        * $this->app and $this->params respectively
        */

        $user = JFactory::getUser();

        $parametrosTask = $this->params->get('task');

        $ignorartask = explode(',', $parametrosTask);       

        if( !in_array(self::getTask(), $ignorartask) && !$user->guest && JURI::base( true ) != "/administrator"){
            self::saveLog(
                self::getDataHora(),
                self::getUsuario(),
                self::getUrl(),
                self::getOption(),
                self::getView(),
                self::getTask(),
                self::getId(),
                self::getItemid(),
                self::getUserid(),
                self::getActivity_id(),
                self::getCid(),
                self::getCatid(),
                self::getModule(),
                self::getFileid(),
                self::getGroupid()
            );
        }       
    }


    function getUsuario()
    {       
        $user = JFactory::getUser();

        if (!$user->guest) {
          return $user->id;
        }

        return '';
    }

    function getUrl()
    {   
        $uri = & JFactory::getURI();
        return $uri->toString();
    }

    function getTask()
    {
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        return $jinput->get('task', '', 'string');
    }

    function getOption()
    {   
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        return $jinput->get('option', '', 'string');        
    }

    function getView()
    {       
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        return $jinput->get('view', '', 'string');
    }

    function getId()
    {       
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        return $jinput->get('id', '', 'int');
    }

    function getItemid()
    {       
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        return $jinput->get('Itemid', '', 'int');
    }

    function getUserid()
    {       
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        return $jinput->get('userid', '', 'string');
    }

    function getActivity_id()
    {       
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        return $jinput->get('activity_id', '', 'string');
    }

    function getCid()
    {       
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        return $jinput->get('cid', '', 'string');
    }

    function getCatid()
    {       
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        return $jinput->get('catid', '', 'string');
    }

    function getModule()
    {       
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        return $jinput->get('module', '', 'string');
    }

    function getFileid()
    {       
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        return $jinput->get('fileid', '', 'string');
    }

    function getDataHora()
    {
        return date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }

    function getGroupid()
    {       
        $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        return $jinput->get('groupid', '', 'string');
    }

    function saveLog(
        $datahora = null,
        $usuario = null,
        $url = null,
        $option = null,
        $view = null,
        $task = null,
        $id = null,
        $Itemid = null,
        $userid = null,
        $activity_id = null,
        $cid = null,
        $catid = null,
        $module = null,
        $fileid = null,
        $groupid = null
        )
    {
        $logaccessuser = new stdClass();        
        $logaccessuser->datahora = $datahora;
        $logaccessuser->usuario = $usuario;
        $logaccessuser->url = $url;
        $logaccessuser->option = $option;
        $logaccessuser->view = $view;
        $logaccessuser->task = $task;
        $logaccessuser->id = $id;
        $logaccessuser->itemid = $Itemid;
        $logaccessuser->userid = $userid;
        $logaccessuser->activity_id = $activity_id;
        $logaccessuser->cid = $cid;
        $logaccessuser->catid = $catid;
        $logaccessuser->module = $module;
        $logaccessuser->fileid = $fileid;
        $logaccessuser->groupid = $groupid;

        // Insert the object into the user profile table.
        $result = JFactory::getDbo()->insertObject('#__logaccessuser', $logaccessuser);
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt this will fix it but would you try `onContentAfterDisplay()` and `onAfterDispatch()` for your plugin? Just wondering if you will get a different result.

Comment: Thank you Walt, I've tried both and the result is the same. I still get 2 records for each page load.

Comment: Hey Rogerio, Does this issue still exist?

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of 2 reasons causing this problem:

- You have an iframe somewhere on your website
- You have installed the same plugin twice (perhaps with a different name)

Comment: Thanks itoctopus, but there´s no iframe.. and the plugin is not installled twice. I believe that another plugin is making the site run twice. What's the best method to debug Joomla, so I can run it step by step?

Comment: Disable all non-core plugins one by one until the issue is resolved.

Comment: I don't think it is a plugin anymore... I have disabled all plugins, just to check it (system, content, all others) and still I get 2 rows for each page load...  what else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your website is trying to load a resource which can't be found - using Joomla!'s .htaccess file, any file/folder that doesn't exist (and if the request doesn't start with index.php) gets routed through index.php.

I'd check to make sure that all of your resources load (JS/CSS/Images/etc) (result in a 200 response)

Comment: Hi Sean, when I first read your comment I thought it could be it. But no, according to FireBug´s NET tab, I don't have any error, all status are 200 or 304 (cached).